# Method of Characterisitcs

Tags: partial-differential-equations

How can I use the method of characteristics in order to solve the following:

\begin{equation}
u(x,b,t)+b.\nabla_xu(x,b,t)=0
\end{equation}

with the following initial condition:

\begin{equation}
u(x,b,0)= |x|+|b|^2
\end{equation}

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have closed your question about discriminant, as I was in the process of writing a solution. Please reopen it and let me know it.

Comment: @JeanMarie Oh my god, im so sorry, Ive reopened it right now, please consider sharing the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is just one derivative (with respect to $x$) in this equation, so it's really an ordinary differential equation with $b$ and $t$ as parameters.  In particular, the "initial condition" can't be of the given form: rather, for each $b$ and $t$ it must specify $u(x_0(b,t), b, t)$ for some
$x_0(b,t)$.